# Enhancing google apps for a Booking System

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for a script that allows me to enhance a booking systeme running with google apps users. I'm not a develloper so i need a bit help, just don't know where to start... Thanks !

Website : https://www.lanacrouse.fr Domain : lanacrouse.fr

I need to :

**In Google Apps Admin :**

- create a new user with just first name and last name :  firstname.lastname@mydomain.fr
- define the password as "mydomain" and ask for a new password at the first connexion
- assign this user to a sub-organisation
- Assign this user to a group

**In Google Calendar :**

- Change the settings in Google Calendar : 
  time zone : "Paris", date format : "31/01/2017", time format : "13:00", weeks start on : "Monday", default view : weeks, custom view : 2 weeks,
- create a new calendar, name : "Indisponibilités", color : "red"
- create a new calendar, name : "first name last name Disponibilités", color : "green", sharing : "public with details", sharing color : "green"
- set the main calendar, name : "first name last name", sharing : "public hidden details", sharing color : "red"
- create recurrent events : calendar : "first name last name Disponibilités", events name : "Présence", time : "from 08:00 to 21:00", repeat: "every monday from first monday of september to last monday of June"
- create same recurrent events for every days except sunday
- activate night time lab "from 08:00 to 21:00"
- activate 2 calendars shared by admin@mydomain.fr with the group this new user belongs

Is it a way to lauch a script from a simple form (first name and last name) hosted on my website with a send button ?

Again thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm not sure on how you can add the Google Apps Admin part in your script, but for the calendar part, you can check this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app) for the ways on how you can do it in the apps script. For example, you can use the `setTimeZone(timeZone)` to set the time zone of the calendar and `createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)` to create an event.

Comment: For your question is there a way to launch a script from a simple form, I think this [blog](http://www.shekhargovindarajan.com/google/google-apps-script-automatically-create-calendar-events-from-google-form/) can help you with that.